getting error trying to connect source to destination in Visual Studio 2019
Component SBT Customer 2 has no inputs, or all its inputs are already connected to other inputs. You may be able to edit the component to add new inputs to it.
Trying to create new components but still getting the same error. Expecting to link source DB and destination DB
